# How can I change the appearance of KDE applications?

Tags: kde, customization, appearance, amarok

I use Gnome. I want to change the appearance of KDE applications such as Amarok. 
The colors in Amarok don't match the rest of my applications. How can I customize them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can install [qt4-qtconfig](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/qt4-qtconfig) :

> `sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig`

this tool to change any Qt 4 apps' theme, it's can mimic GTK theme too for Qt, but if there is any qt3 apps, use [qt3-qtconfig](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/qt3-qtconfig)

> `sudo apt-get install qt3-qtconfig`

Comment: Note that Qt4 apps mimic your Gtk theme by default (at least in recent versions of Ubuntu), so you don't need to install `qt4-qtconfig` to do it. Qt3 has no option to mimic your Gtk theme, so installing `sudo apt-get install qt3-qtconfig` will only help if there is a Qt3 version of your Gtk theme.

Comment: Is there any way to test this without messing up and then remove it if undesired? Thanks.